# how to connect API Printify with django

Tags: django, api, django-views

I have problems connecting to the printify api with django, I am not very practical so I would need to understand why and above all what to pass as parameters

views:

```
def home(request):
    token = settings.TOKEN_PRINTIFY
    headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Authorization' : 'Bearer ' + token}
    response = requests.get('https://api.printify.com/v1/shops', headers = headers)
    print('-----------------', response) #error 404

    context = {}
    return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

the response it gives me how 401 status and I don't understand where to put that token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are not params but headers
replace `params=payload` by:

```
{headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json', Authorization : 'Bearer ' + token}}
```